# Order by a specific column in MYSQL, with extra condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

There is a table

```
Teacher
--------
id
name
country_id
```

I can simply order the teacher with `order by country_id asc` , however, how to provide a specific id then order by?

For example , I would like the result with country_id 3 to be first , that means if there is country id 1 or 2, they should be after the country id 3

```
e.g. 

teacherA 3
teacherB 3
teacherC 1
teacherD 4
etc..
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use Field().
It would be something like order by Field(country_id, 3, 2), this will give you country id with 3 first followed by country id 2 and then everything else will be ordered.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY IF(country_id = 3, 0, 1),
         country_id
```